# OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut on the same element to create hover effect using javascript only?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and for practice, I am using javascript to stripe even rows for tables with a particular class. Besides that, I am trying to create a 'hover' effect on table rows using javascript only.

I was able to create the onmouseover effect, however, I am having a very difficult time going back to the default style onmouseout of the table row.

Please keep in mind that I know this can easily be achieved with css or JQuery; however, for this, I would like to stick to javscript only.

What I tried:

```
    function alternate(){
        var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");     

        //apply the code to ALL tables on the page with a particular class
        for (var ti = 0; ti < tables.length; ++ti) {
            if (tables[ti].className == "striped"){ //stripe tables
                var rows = tables[ti].getElementsByTagName("tr");   
                for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){           
                    //change style of even rows to create striped effect
                    if(i % 2 == 0){ 
                        rows[i].className += "even"; //stripe even rows while maintaining default style to odd rows
                    }
                    rows[i].onmouseover = function() {
                        this.className="";
                        this.className="hovered";
                    }
                    rows[i].onmouseout = function() { 
                        if(i % 2 == 0){
                            this.className="even";
                        }else{
                            this.className="odd";
                        }                       
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, didn't see that. But however, "this" probably isn't what you wanna use there since it references the anonymus function.

Comment: Wait, I might be wrong here.

Comment: Hm, works for me - what was the question? How you can tell on mouseOut if it was even or odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I quite understood your question, but I have created a jsfiddle which does what I think you meant.

The problem, from what I could tell, was that when row[i].mouseout is triggered, the value of i is the number of tables rows in your table. The fix is, to save the original classname on mouseover, and then re-assign that classname onmouseout. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LBaZu/4/

```
function alternate() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for (var ti = 0; ti < tables.length; ++ti) {
        if (tables[ti].className == "striped") {
            var rows = tables[ti].getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var cls; // Variable to save the className
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) rows[i].className = "even";
                rows[i].onmouseover = function() {
                    cls = this.className;  // Assign the className here
                    this.className = "hovered";
                }
                rows[i].onmouseout = function() {
                    this.className = (cls == 'even') ? cls : 'odd';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I re-read your question and it occurred to me that you only wanted to set the odd table rows classname to odd on mouseout, not before.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thank you very much. When you assign this.className to the 'cls' variable, what gets saved in the 'cls' variable? the current class that is assigned to the row (if any) that the mouse just hovered off of? OR all styling that was applied to the row (even if it wasn't a literally a 'class'), before it was hovered???

Comment: The value that gets assigned to 'cls' is the current className of the <tr> tag that the mouse just moved within the bounds of. For example, when you mouseover a <tr> tag with a className of 'even'. The string 'even' is saved in the 'cls' variable. If there is no className, an empty string is assigned to the variable 'cls'. In short, a string value is saved in the 'cls' variable, whether there is or is not an existing className.